# Compilation errors while compiling WordCount.java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I keep getting an error which says 'cannot find symbol' while compiling WordCount.java. I tried importing the other libraries, but it only adds up to the list of errors. Am I missing some component that needs to be added?

```
  javac -classpath /Documents/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:/Documents/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java


    WordCount.java:4: error: package org.apache.hadoop.fs does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
                               ^
    WordCount.java:5: error: package org.apache.hadoop.io does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
    ^
    WordCount.java:6: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
    ^
    WordCount.java:8: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
                                             ^
    WordCount.java:9: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.output does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
                                          ^
    WordCount.java:10: error: package org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input does not exist
    import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
                                         ^
    WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,    Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                        ^
    symbol:   class MapReduceBase
    location: class WordCount
    WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,   Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                 ^
    symbol:   class Mapper
    location: class WordCount
    WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,     Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                        ^
    symbol:   class LongWritable
    location: class WordCount
    WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                      ^
    symbol:   class Text
    location: class WordCount 
    WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,     Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                             ^
    symbol:   class Text
    location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                                  ^
    symbol:   class IntWritable
    location: class WordCount
    WordCount.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
          private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
                               ^
    symbol:   class IntWritable
    location: class Map
    WordCount.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
          private Text word = new Text();
                  ^
    symbol:   class Text
    location: class Map
    WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                          ^
    symbol:   class LongWritable
    location: class Map
    WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable>   output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                            ^
    symbol:   class Text
    location: class Map
    WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable>     output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                        ^
    symbol:   class OutputCollector
    location: class Map
    WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                              ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
          public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Reporter
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                           ^
  symbol:   class MapReduceBase
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                    ^
  symbol:   class Reducer
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                            ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                               ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
        public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
                                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                             ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class OutputCollector
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                                     ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                                           ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
          public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
                                                                                                                ^
  symbol:   class Reporter
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
          private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
                                                     ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
          private Text word = new Text();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class Map
WordCount.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
                                    ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class Reduce
WordCount.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
          JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
          ^
  symbol:   class JobConf
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
          JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
                             ^
  symbol:   class JobConf
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
          conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
                                 ^
  symbol:   class Text
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
          conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class IntWritable
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
          conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
                              ^
  symbol:   class TextInputFormat
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
          conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
                               ^
  symbol:   class TextOutputFormat
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
          FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
          FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
          ^
  symbol:   variable FileInputFormat
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Path
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:53: error: cannot find symbol
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));
          ^
  symbol:   variable FileOutputFormat
  location: class WordCount
WordCount.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
      JobClient.runJob(conf);
      ^
  symbol:   variable JobClient
  location: class WordCount
46 errors
```

Comment: Tip: Try an IDE such as Eclipse or NetBeans, it makes development a million times easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
javac -classpath hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar:lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d [path where u want to put the result] [path]/WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your classpath doesn't include all required libs and jars.

For hadoop 2.7 you can easily run:

```
$hadoop classpath
```

This will return the full list of libs and jars which you need to include in your classpath.

or simpler you can just use the above command when you are compiling your code

```
$  javac -classpath $(hadoop classpath) -d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the necessary packages are not included in javac classpath.

For hadoop 2.7.3, adding 3 packages works for me:

```
javac -classpath $HADOOP_HOME$/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar:$HADOOP_HOME$/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.jar:$HADOOP_HOME$/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar
-d wordcount_classes WordCount.java
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers cut to the chase and give pragmatic, quick solutions - which will work - but the [official Hadoop Wordcount tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) recommends that you call `javac` from `bin/hadoop`.  This way, Hadoop will take care of the classpath conflicts for its own libraries.

The [above-mentioned tutorial](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.4/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html) could however mislead you to point `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` to the wrong `lib` directory (there are distinct ones for the JDK and the JRE) thus missing `tools.jar`.*****

My solution is to proceed as follow:

```
$ export HADOOP_PREFIX="${absolute/path/to/your/hadoop/binaries}"
$ export JDK_HOME="${absolute/path/to/your/jdk}"  

$ export JAVA_HOME="${JDK_HOME}/jre"  
$ export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"  
$ export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="${JDK_HOME}/lib/tools.jar"  

$ cd $HADOOP_PREFIX
$ bin/hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main ./path/to/WordCount.java
```

**Note** that the actual values to assign to `JAVA_HOME` and `HADOOP_PREFIX` must point to the locations where those tools are actually installed on your machine.

---

* it would cause `Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main` at compile-time