# "Cannot find symbol" error in Hadoop WordCount Example

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I am trying to work through this Hadoop MapReduce Word Count example given in the book *Data Analytics with Hadoop* which had me setup a Hadoop pseudo-distributed development environment. So now I am trying to run a Word Count example. I downloaded the .java files, WordCount folder, from [Hadoop Fundamentals](https://github.com/bbengfort/hadoop-fundamentals). The code given in the book to start this process is:

```
hostname $ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main WordCount.java
```

I run this and receive the following errors:

```
hadoop@gh0st-VirtualBox:/home/gh0st$ hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main Downloads/WordCount/WordCount.java
Downloads/WordCount/WordCount.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
        job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
                           ^
  symbol:   class WordMapper
  location: class WordCount
Downloads/WordCount/WordCount.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        job.setReducerClass(SumReducer.class);
                            ^
  symbol:   class SumReducer
  location: class WordCount
Note: Downloads/WordCount/WordCount.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
```

The WordMapper.java and SumReducer.java files are located in the same WordCount folder from which I'm running the WordCount.java file. I'm not sure where to start from here considering all I read regarding this. My `$JAVA_HOME` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/`. My `$CLASS_PATH` is `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.7.3.jar`. I'm not sure what other information is needed to fix this issue--I'll add whatever else is needed. The following links are what I looked at and tried:

[Hadoop Problems](http://www.lifeincode.net/programming/hadoop-problems-when-running-simple-examples/)

[Compilation Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600927/compilation-errors-while-compiling-wordcount-java)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 within VirtualBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after some deep digging, I found the answer. The answer is in the comment in the following link: [Driver Class Compilation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570205/driver-class-compilation-error-hadoop-mapreduce)

I had to compile all the files together. The new code looks like this:

`hadoop com.sun.tools.javac.Main Downloads/WordCount/WordCount.java Downloads/WordCount/WordMapper.java Downloads/WordCount/SumReducer.java`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. Export `Hadoop classpath`:

```
export CLASSPATH=`hadoop classpath`
```

2. Check the path does exist:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

3. Run all of them at the same time:

```
javac -d . WC_Runner.java WC_Mapper.java WC_Reducer.java
```